# Use Mirth as an API listener, NOT using Mirth to initiate the API payload

Tags: api, tcplistener, httplistener, mirth

We have a desire to have a sending application send an API post to Mirth with a payload of data.  Mirth receives this payload via a Listener and then transforms it in a destination into a HL7 format and off to a RIS.

I'm having an issue setting this up.  I believe I should be using an HTTP Listener to achieve this.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an `HTTP Listener Source Connector`. You can read more about all its options on page 325 from the [User guide](https://www.nextgen.com/-/media/files/nextgen-connect/nextgen-connect-311-user-guide.pdf)

After receiving a REST POST request, `HTTP Listener Source Connector` sends the payload to the connector/transformer flow where you can work as usual with it.

Answer (score 0):

Also see this guide on creating a REST service on Mirth.

http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/wiki/display/mirth/Creating+a+custom+REST+Service+in+Mirth+3.0.x